# Python 2 Enum Example

Tags: python, enums

I found this code which is supposed to illustrate how enums work. I'm aware things are differnt now in Python 3, but I want to make sense of this example. What do I need to input to get `print("You chose the easy option")` to execute please?

I've tried `1`, `Easy` and `Choice.Easy` so far with no success.

```
def enum(**enums):
    return type('Enum', (), enums)

Choice = enum(Easy = 1, Medium = 2, Hard = 3)
choice = input("Enter choice: ")

if choice == Choice.Easy:
    print("You chose the easy option")
elif choice == Choice.Medium:
    print("You chose the medium option")
elif choice == Choice.Hard:
    print("You chose the hard option")
else: 
    print("You should choose one of the three levels!")
```

Comment: Python 2 will no longer be supported in less than *one month*. **Do not use it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example does not create an enum, just a class with some members that have integer values.

The reason it is not working in Python 3 is because in Python 2 `input()` `eval`ed whatever was entered, so typing `1` actually returned an `int`; in Python 3 `input` became the same as Python 2's `raw_input()`, which returns `str`s and makes you do any necessary conversions.

In other words:

- Python 2

```
    >>> input('give me a number: ')
    give me a number:                # enter '1' and hit <Enter>
    1                                # returns the int 1
```

- Python 3

```
    >>> input('give me a number: ')
    give me a number:                # enter '1' and hit <Enter>
    '1'                              # returns the str '1'
```

For actual `Enum`s, use either the stdlib `enum` module or the third-party [`aenum`](https://pypi.org/project/aenum/)<sup>1</sup> module (which supports advanced `Enum` creation as well as having Python 2 support).

An actual `Enum` would look like this:

```
from enum import Enum          # or from aenum import Enum

class Choice(Enum):
    Easy = 1
    Medium = 2
    Hard = 3
```

and converting user input:

```
choice = input("Enter choice: ")
choice = Choice(int(choice))

if choice is Choice.Easy:        # NB: use `is` instead of `==` for normal enums
    ...
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Answer (score 2):

The input which user has entered is string type and in Choice it has integer.
Make change:

```
Choice = enum(Easy = '1', Medium = '2', Hard = '3')
```

or

```
choice = int(input("Enter choice: "))
```

in this case you need to handle exception valueError

Answer (score 1):

This is not working because you are comparing string with integer. you can take input as integer.

```
choice = int(input("Enter choice: "))
```